# Obtaining touch location inside a TouchDragInside method

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

How do I obtain the touch location inside a TouchDragInside method when there is no event parameter passed to the method?

Obviously this does not work:

```
- (IBAction)touchDragInsideDblTapSignBut:(id)sender {
   UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my viewDidLoad I had to add this:

```
[_dblTapSignAddBut addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDragInsideDblTapSignButE:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

And then create a void method:

```
- (void) touchDragInsideDblTapSignButE:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
   NSLog(@"Location x%f y%f",location.x,location.y);
}
```